# Reach nested divs with bs4 and requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to grab information with bs4 from a website that has nested divs. I've tried below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "something"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
w = soup.find("div", {"id":"content"})
```

And this works fine. But now `w` is not a BeautifulSoup object and I cannot repeat the same tactic again. Naively:

```
w2 = w.find("div", {"id": "some nested div"})
```

How do I access nested divs with BeautifulSoup and requests?

Comment: *...I cannot repeat the same tactic again* . Why? Code should work as expected

Comment: make it again a bs object. Load it again.

Comment: w is indeed a bs4.element.Tag object. No need to make it an object again. As @Andersson said, the code should work as expected.